# How to write style to WPF DataGridColumnHeader

Tags: c#, css, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I want to write style for WPF DataGrid Column Header . My grid as follows

```
`<DataGrid >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                      <Label Content="{DynamicResource colName}"></Label>
                 </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>`
```

I want to bind label content using DynamicResource. This code is working properly. I want write a style to apply this binding method to grid column. I wrilte a style as follows.

```
`<Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" > 
     <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                           <Label Content="{ TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                   </ControlTemplate>
             </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
</Style>`
```

I apply this style to grid as follows.

```
<DataGrid >
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn  HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" Header="{ DynamicResource colName}"  />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

After using style header not binding. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

We can try as follows

```
<Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="dg:DataGridColumnHeader">   
                <dg:DataGridHeaderBorder
                x:Name="headerBorder"                      
                Background="Red">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" 
                        CornerRadius="2" 
                        Background="Black"
                        BorderBrush="Green">                            
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding  Content}" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"/>                                
                        </Grid>                                
                </Border>
                </dg:DataGridHeaderBorder>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>                 
</Style>
<dg:DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" 
                 Name="UserName"                      
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                 Width="800"                       
                 Background="Yellow"
                 ColumnHeaderHeight="20"                       
                 ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource ColumnHeaderStyle}"
                 RowStyle="{StaticResource RowStyle}"
                 CanUserAddRows="False"
                 CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                 />
```

Comment: Error 1 DataGridHeaderBorder is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project.

Comment: Just add a namespace reference like this:
xmlns:dg="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero">
You may have to manually add a reference to PresentationFramework.Aero in your project

Comment: How I add test prefix to grid?

Comment: xmlns:dg="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.‌​Aero"> In place of test you can replace dg.

Answer (score 1):

Define `Header` as a `StaticResource` not Dynamic. This will fix your issue

```
<DataGridTextColumn  HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" Header="{ StaticResource colName}"  />
```

Or you can update your controlTemplate's label to have `DynamicResource` and no need of giving `Header` then.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Label Content="{ DynamicResource colName}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: I binding a dictionary to Resource Directory. 'colName' is a key of that dictionary. When that dictionary has a key call 'colName' header bind properly when using StaticResource. but when that binding dictionary not having a key call 'colName' given an exceptions. Thats why I use template bindng. Otherwise I don't want to use style and I can directly bind grid header as a StaticResource

Comment: so you want your  header to be blank if you dont have colName key in dictionary?

Comment: How I add ControlTemplate to grid?

Comment: it is the same template you defined in your style

Comment: Datagrid have DataGridTemplateColumn to template column bindings. Thats how I used here. I cant find ControlTemplate property in Datagrid. DataGridTemplateColumn using repeatedly not good practice. that why I want a style.